# assigning user input to a variable in php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Am building my firs php program, the problem am facing is assigning the user input to a variable

here is my code

```
<?php
printf("Enter student test mark");
$test = read_stdin();

    function read_stdin()
{
        $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
        $input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
        $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
        fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
        return $input;                  // return the text entered
}



printf("Enter student assignment mark");

?>
```

how can i let the user input a number and assign it to the test variable

Comment: You have to use [tag:html] PHP is a server side language, it's there for processing the information

Comment: @Bankzilla but i want to build simple console program, aren't there any other simpler way? like using scanner in java?

Comment: That's not how php is used, perhaps you're looking for something more towards [tag:ruby]

Comment: @Bankzilla PHP can be used with a CLI!

Comment: @Bankzillaam am new to scripting in general, i don't have much knowledge, am want to build the program using pure php only, without involving other languages

Comment: @Rizier123 It can be used CLI but it's not an interactive shell

Comment: This seems to be working, what's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $test = $_POST['marks'];//assigning your input value

        if(isset($test))
        {
            $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
            $input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
            $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
            fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
            $result =  $input;              // return the text entered
        }
    }

?>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="marks" placeholder="Enter student test mark">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<?php
if(empty($result))
{

}
else
{
  echo ' Enter student assignment mark';
}
```

or else you can show all input box first and then assign to your variables and do the your calculations as well

Comment: Would need to put a check on the assigning of `$test` it will throw a warning on page load

Comment: Try `$test = !empty($_POST['marks']) ? $_POST['marks'] : null;` then instead of testing if `$test` isset. Use `if(!is_null($test))`. Reason being, the user can still submit nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample i made to test your code there, and your code seems to be working..

named this `sample.php`[FILE] inside `/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop`[DIR]

under `Terminal.app`

```
cd [DIR] // cd  /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop

php [FILE] // php sample.php
```

> sample.php

```
<?php

    function read_stdin()
    {
        $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
        $input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
        $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
        fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
        return $input;                  // return the text entered
    }

    printf("Enter 1st number:");
    $num1 = read_stdin();

    printf("Enter 2nd number:");
    $num2 = read_stdin();

    echo "Equation: ".$num1." + ".$num2." = ".($num1 + $num2)."\n";

?>
```

> Sample output

```
Enter 1st number :1
Enter 2nd number :2
Equation : 1 + 2 = 3
```